# The first line breakpoint works only

Tags: android, debugging, breakpoints

I am developing in Android Studio (i've used IntelliJ IDEA + SDK)
I've encountered debugging problem. All my breakpoints don't work in all projects.
Exclusion is the breakpoint on the first line of a method
for example:
[image]
Breakpoint on line 1 works, on line 2 doesn't
breakpoint's Hint tells that no sources found for this line. It seems like proguard is enabled, but it doesn't.

I have tried create new empty project (Gradle). It is also not working.
Have You any idea?

Comment: What does line 1 mean?  Do you mean the method signature? (public View.....) What does "don't work" mean?

Comment: can you add a screenshot? Are you adding a breakpoints on all the lines or you are using steps?

Comment: Line 1 means - "View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orderlist_fragment, container, false);" I've added link to main post.

Comment: Eclipse/ADT package works great.  I haven't tried Studio, because it is still beta.

Comment: It seems like Studio cannot resolve your resource, these posts might help: [Android Studio cannot find my resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344019/android-studio-cannot-find-my-resources), [Android Studio marks R in red with error message “cannot resolve symbol R”, but build succeeds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but)

Answer (score 6):

I've solved the problem. I was running debugging on a real device (Nexus 4 with Android 4.4 KitKat). And I' have enabled **ART instead Dalvik** on the device. All breakpoint start to work when i've switched back to Dalvik.